# add space between two bootstrap columns when viewed in col-xs-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when the browser is resized to the mobile sized screen, the two columns in property of col-xs-12 are displayed without any gap.can anyone show how to fix this?
[when viewed in large size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqfyp.png)

[when viewed in small size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhSn1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a media query of your own. So give the bottom one a class like "small-margin-top" and then add this to css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
 .small-margin-top{
     margin-top: 3em;
  }
}
```

Adjust this to your liking and specifications. I know that bootstrap uses "min-width" instead of "max-width" like I showed you. So do your research on that end to make sure it flows but it should work regardless.